# OnClick JavaScript não funcionando com "quebra de linha"

Tags: javascript, onclick

Estou um problema, eu pego uma informações inseridas pelo usuário no banco de dados e coloco ele em um *button* com *onclick* para ao usuário clicar coloca-lo em um modal para que ele posso editar, não posso colocar direto no modal pois são varias informações então e elas tem que ir mudando dependendo de onde o usuário clica, o problema surge quando vem informações com quebra de linha, (o usuário utilizou um enter durante a inserção da informação), o *onclick* simplismente não funciona e da um alerta: **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"**.
 O que me deixou intrigado que com caracteres especiais funciona normalmente, apenas com a quebra de linha que não. Segue abaixo o código do button:

```
<button class="btnEdit btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="editar(\'' + value.nome + '\' , \'' + value.modulo + '\' , \'' + value.roteiro + '\' ,' + value.id + ')"  ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>';
```

Comment: então, esse enter vai gerar uma "constante de cadeia não finalizada" no javascript. Tem que tratar essa entrada retirando as quebras de linhas. Mostra como é que esses dados são passados para o botão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então, você tem que tratar de retirar essas quebras de linhas para não gerar erro de "`constante de cadeia não finalizada`" no javascript.

Para evitar esse erro você pode eliminar as quebras de linhas quando "pegar as informações inseridas pelo usuário no banco de dados", ou seja no select, da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT REPLACE(
REPLACE(NOME-COLUNA, '\r', '\\r'),
'\n',
'\\n'
) FROM NOME_TABELA;
```

Exemplo: tabela utilizada

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No Javascript é uma linha unica sem quebra e portanto sem gerar erros.

```js
console.log("Essa coluna tem\r\nquebra de linha\r\nduas veazes\r\nponto final");
```

No entanto com quebra de linha ...

```js
 console.log("Essa coluna tem\r\nquebra de linha\r\nduas 

        veazes\r\nponto final");
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando você for escrever no HTML as quebras de linha devem ser representadas por "\n", portanto você deve Substituir os caracteres de quebra de linha por "\n".
Exemplo:

```html
<html>
<body>
  <input type="button" onclick="alert('Oi, \nTudo bem com você? \n Espero que sim.');" value="Botão" />
</body>
</html>
```

Exemplo de Replace se você gerar o código HTML a partir do Javascript:

```
variavel.replace("\n","\\n")
```

Comment: Rafael implementei sua solução, infelizmente não funcionou, pode ser o formato que vem do mysql?

Comment: Copia o código gerado e coloca como exemplo na pergunta. Você substituiu a quebra de linha como fiz no exemplo? Qual linguagem você usa ?

Comment: peguei como ficou no debug, ficou assim:

**<button class="btnEdit btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="editar('teste2' , 'discador' , 'este é um teste
\n mensagem teste' ,10,1)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>**